# How to connect to a embedded Derby database?

Tags: java, derby, embedded-database, datagrip

I am using Netbeans and a embedded Derby database in a small Java project.

I would like to see the structure and data of the database as when I use PgAdmin or DataGrip with PostgreSQL databases.

It is my first time using and embedded database so I am not sure if it is possible.

I tried to connect using DataGrip but it ask for a path.

[image: DataGrip ask for a path.]

Comment: Since it's your first time working with Derby, start by working through the Derby tutorials: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/getstart/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the path: **NetBeansProjects/myProject/databaseName**

Then click the button to download the driver if it wasn't downloaded before.

And then the connection can be tested with the **Test Connection** button.